# ¿Cómo importar una librería externa de javascript a un componente en angular?

Tags: typescript, angular

Buen día comunidad,

Estoy trabajando con angular 5+ y estoy tratando de utilizar una librería hecha en javascript en mis componentes de typescript. Por ahí estuve buscando y decía que utilizara el siguiente método de importación:

```
import * as docuvieware from '../../../docuvieware/docuvieware-min.js';
```

sin embargo, a la hora de compilar y correr el proyecto con "ng serve" me da el error:

> ERROR in node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.symbol.wellknown.d.ts(145,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.
>   node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(952,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.
>   node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es5.d.ts(979,15): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'JSON'.
>   src/app/components/detalleExpediente/detalleExpediente.component.ts(6,30): error TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/angular gd + asp/Nueva carpeta/prueba/src/docuvieware/docuvieware-min.js' is not a module.

Answer (score 1):

Como sugerencia puedes importar estas librerías en el archivo `angular.json`
en esta parte del archivo:

```
"scripts": [
              "src/js/tu archivo.js"
            ]
          },
```

Yo no he encontrado una solución al problema y debo trabajarlo desde Javascript. espero ser de ayuda.